# Pointers with preprocessor directives

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Working on a code I've seen this:

```
#define X(i)        ((array[i]).x[0])
#define Y(i)        ((array[i]).y[0])

typedef struct {
  int x[2];
  int y[2];
} coord_t;

coord_t* array = malloc(sizeof(coord_t)* 10);
int myX = X(5);
```

This makes the access to `array` almost hardcoded with `X` and `Y` preprocessor directives. What I would like to do is to pass the pointer to the preprocessor directive, something like:

```
#define X(myarray,i) myarray[i].x[0]
```

where `myarray` could be any `coord_t` pointer:

```
coord_t* a = malloc(sizeof(coord_t)* 4);
coord_t* b = malloc(sizeof(coord_t)* 12);

int myX = X(a,1);
int myotherX = X(b,6);
```

I've done this, and it compiles without any errors however I am not getting the same results. My question is, can I `#define X` in this way?

Comment: Not really met the problem but be aware that `malloc` does not initialise the memory so `int myX = X(5);` is *undefined behaviour*. Moreover using macros to access that memory makes the code obscure.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Apologies for that, updated now.

Comment: @Manolete you also have a typo in your suggested macro: `.X[0]` should then be `.x[0]`

Comment: Could `#define X(myarray, i)  ((coord_t)myarray[i]).x[0]` be the solution?

Comment: you are not getting the same results because you code results in undefined behavior, you have not initialized the memory returned by malloc

Comment: @Manolete No, the original macro is correct. You cannot cast to array types anyway. If you are still having trouble (after fixing the problem of accessing uninitialized memory) then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem.

Comment: Use functions instead of macros!

Comment: @Matthias It's a good idea, but sometimes one cannot choose.

Comment: Well, it's [your choice](https://godbolt.org/g/79PQoX)...

Answer (score -1):

```
#define X(myarray,i) myarray[i].x[0]
```